# Possible to put CheckedTextView into Group like RadioGroup?

Tags: android, checkedtextview

Is there a way to have multiple `CheckedTextView` in some sort of group like `RadioGroup`? So only one `CheckedTextView` would be checked at the same time.

If this is not possible as `CheckedTextView` is a child of `TextView`, what is the most memory efficient way to code logic that only **one `CheckedTextView`** can be checked in the group of 5 other `CheckedTextViews`?

It does not look memory efficient that each time one `CheckedTextView` is pressed, I check for the check state of all others and change it accordingly.

Comment: The simplest way is to use custom drawable like checkbox for radio buttons..

Comment: Thanks. This link also helped me to create my own logic http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509329/437039

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with `CheckedTextView` to behave as part of some group (e.g. only one `CheckedTextView` can be selected at a time).

```
//pass view which fired onClick event
//pass an array or other container of checkedTextViews (optional)
void setCheckedState(View v, CheckedTextView[] whichCheckedViews) {
    CheckedTextView temp = (CheckedTextView) v;

//first uncheck all views in the arraw
    for (CheckedTextView item : whichCheckedViews)
        item.setChecked(false);

//detect which checkedTextView initiated onClick event
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkedTextView_1:
        case R.id.checkedTextView_2:
        case R.id.checkedTextView_3:
        case R.id.checkedTextView_N:
            temp.setChecked(true);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And this works like a charm.

**NOTE:** I did not check memory consumption since I have only 5 views. I also did not check execution time since on all test devices it runs without a glitch.