# Checkbox inside a spinner validation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, spinner

I have multiple checkboxes inside a spinner. How to validate it when nothing is selected.

```
if(spinner_inperson.getSelectedItem()!="select"){
        //Toast.makeText(spinner_crop_sown.this, "Unesite ime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Inperson Spinner Dropdown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the sample code which I tried

Comment: make a model of checkboxes and handle its status

Comment: may b duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121997/android-check-box-group

Comment: @Priyankagb I tried it but its not working